the function $h(x,y) = x t^y$ product of linear and strictly convex function is convex?
Is the function $h(x,y) = x t^y$  convex in the region $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ when $t$ is a constant between 0 and 1?
Content: I would like to know if the function $h(x,y) = x t^y$ is convex in the region $x > 0$ and $y > 0$, where $t$) is a constant in the interval $(0,1)$.
When I visualise this in 3D graph, it appears to be a convex function in this region. However, I am struggling to prove it mathematically. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
(add comment)
I also verified that it has a saddle point using the Hessian matrix. However, it seems that the Hessian matrix cannot be used to confirm whether the function is convex in the region where (x>0) and (y>0), since it's about confirming convexity in a specific region rather than the entire domain. Can the Hessian matrix be used to check convexity in a specific region as well?
Thank you in advance.

Hessian of the function is $H=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &  t^{y}\ln(t) \\
t^{y}\ln(t) &x\ln^2(t)t^y
\end{bmatrix}$
$det(H) = -t^{2y}\ln^2(t)\le 0$. Thus, H is indefinite and nonconvex

@MartinR Thank you for pointing it out. I corrected the answer. Hopefully, nothing wrong in my calculation this time..

I also verified that it has a saddle point using the Hessian matrix. However, it seems that the Hessian matrix cannot be used to confirm whether the function is convex in the region where (x>0) and (y>0), since it's about confirming convexity in a specific region rather than the entire domain.

@dizzy it's indefinite in that region, hence nonconvex

thank for comment

$H$ is indefinite (and the function not convex or concave) because its determinant is strictly negative, and that is because $t \in (0, 1)$. For $t=1$ you have $\det H = 0$ and $h(x, y) = x$, which is convex.
